# WP_Query retuning empty array in rest api

Tags: wp-query, hooks, rest-api, troubleshooting

I recently started writing a rest api for my plugin. I need to access some custom posts however WP_Query is returning an empty array when I'm querying the db.

There is the custom post type declaration.

```
// custom post type declaration
add_action('init', 'register_plugin_custom_post_type');
function register_plugin_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type('my_post_type', 
        [
            'label' => "A name",
            'StackExchange exemple',
            'public' => false,
            'show_in_rest' => true
        ]);
}
```

Rest api route registration

```
add_action('wp_rest_init', 'my_plugin_rest_init_callback');
function my_plugin_wp_rest_callback() {
    register_rest_route('my-rest-route', '/endpoint', 
        [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'rest_api_callback',
            'permission_callback' => function() {
                return current_user_can('manage_options');
            }
        ]);
}
```

The rest api callbacks

```
// Rest api callback using wp_query
function rest_api_callback() {
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type'
    ];

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Here $posts is empty 
    $posts = $query->get_posts();
}
```

```
// same function using wpdb
function rest_api_callback() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = "{$wpdb->prefix}posts";
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM $table WHERE post_type='my_post_type';"

    // Here $post_ids is [ 0 => ID0, 1 => ID1, ..., n => IDn]
    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);
}
```

Is there is a way to use wp_query in the WordPress rest api ?

Comment: Where/how are you calling `rest_api_callback()`?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're requiring the `manage_options` capability on your endpoint. Are you authenticating before you try to get the API data? Being signed in to the website doesn't translate to API authentication, IIRC. (To test this, you can replace your anonymous function with `__return_true` to see if the capability requirement is the problem.)